# How to rename sub directory and file names recursively in script python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a recursive directory. Both subdirectory and files names have illegal characters. I have a function to clean up the names, such as it replaces a space with an underscore in the name. There must be an easier way but I couldn't find a way to both rename folders and files. So, I want to rename the folders first.

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in subdirs:     
            new_name=clean_names(name)
            name=os.path.join(path,name)
            new_name=os.path.join(path,new_name) 
            os.chdir(path)
            os.rename(name,new_name)
```

When I check my real folder and it contents I see that only the first subfolder name is corrected. I can see the reason because `os.chdir(path)` changes the cwd then it doesn't change back before for loop starts to second path. I thought after the os.rename I could rechange the cwd but I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this. If I remove the os.chdir line it gives filenotfound error.

I see that renaming subdirectories has been asked about before, but they are in command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `os.walk(root, topdown=False)` instead; otherwise once the top folder gets renamed, `os.walk` won't have access to the subfolders because it can no longer find their parent folders.

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> If optional argument `topdown` is `True` or not specified, the triple for
>   a directory is generated before the triples for any of its
>   subdirectories (directories are generated top-down). If `topdown` is
>   `False`, the triple for a directory is generated after the triples for
>   all of its subdirectories (directories are generated bottom-up). No
>   matter the value of topdown, the list of subdirectories is retrieved
>   before the tuples for the directory and its subdirectories are
>   generated.

Note that you do not need to call `os.chdir` at all because all the paths passed to `os.rename` are absolute.